# SQL Server 2014 - Cast Date effecting results

Tags: sql, casting, sql-server-2014

What is the different between the two conditions below? DateRecordCreated is a DTM field.

1. `cast([DateRecordCreated] as date) >= '2014-07-04' and cast([DateRecordCreated] as date) <= '2014-07-10'`
2. `[DateRecordCreated] >= '2014-07-04' and [DateRecordCreated] <= '2014-07-10'`

They look like the same condition but give me different results. #2 gives me a lower number.

Answer (score 2):

The second one has a time component.  So, `DateRecordCreated` is being compared to the date `2014-07-10` *without* the time (in the second case).  That means that any value not exactly at midnight is going to fail the test.

The first version chops off the time component, so it would include all times on that date.

As a general rule, I would write this logic as:

```
[DateRecordCreated] >= '2014-07-04' and [DateRecordCreated] < '2014-07-11'
```

Aaron Bertrand actually has a very useful blog on this topic.  I would recommend that you read [it](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).